# Double line while hover

Tags: html, css

Please go to this website: http://dev.taarana.org.my/
Go to the Business Lines, and hover to the Property Developement & Project Management.

The menu is turn to double line while hovering.

How prevent this? I would like to maintain it in single line.

Comment: its not getting turn to double line and not even single line

Comment: what do you mean? I mean the word "Property Developement & Project Management" is not in single line while hovering

Comment: I couldn't see as well, not even a single line.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely due to the font being changed to font-weight:bold; This will increase the width of the text and so it's wrapping to the next line. You'll need to increase the width of your menu or decrease the size of your text or alternatively not make it bold on hover.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are changing the font to bold, which is making the text wider than the menu.

Change the width of the `ul` with the class `"sub-menu"` to `24.5em`.

Comment: I am using wordpress. Its not in CSS, its the menu element style. Now i dont know where to locate this element style.

Answer (score 0):

YA.. I got the issue ...you will be required to increase width assign to sub menu..OR reduce the long text heading given as "Property Developement & Project Management" something small

Comment: It still not working, i just can change the word and to "&" but it still showing double line. I add white-space: nowrap; but this code is not working in IE

Comment: Increase the width assigned to submenu

Comment: The problem is i dont find the submenu element, its not available in the CSS.